# Can't rewrite a URL including the query string components

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to do some URL rewriting in asp.net core 2.2 but it doesn't seem to work with the query string part. I want to change any path like "finditem?txn=3" into something like "find/item?transactionid=3". As a simpler example, without a smart replacement of the transactionID, look at this code:

```
private static RewriteOptions GetRewriteOptions() => new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^bananatxn=\d$", "Download", true) // Works with bananatxn=1
    .AddRewrite(@"^banana\?txn=\d$", "Download", true); // Does NOT work with banana?txn=1
```

Why can't the rewriter match on the question mark character? I've tested my patterns in http://regexstorm.net/tester and although the pattern seems to be correct it doesn't work. Can the rewriter in asp.net core rewrite the entire URL, including the query string, or only the part before the question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigate and think (but am not sure) this functionality is not available in the built-in rules provided by asp.net core. This worked for me. Definitely NOT tested thoroughly, probably gives too much importance to upper and lower case, and I'm not super familiar with all the URL components and formats.

```
public class RewritePathAndQuery : IRule
{
    private Regex _regex;
    private readonly string _replacement;
    private readonly RuleResult _resultIfRewrite;

    /// <param name="regex">Pattern for the path and query, excluding the initial forward slash.</param>
    public RewritePathAndQuery(string regex, string replacement, bool skipRemainingRules)
    {
        _regex = new Regex(regex);
        _replacement = replacement;
        _resultIfRewrite = skipRemainingRules ? RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules : RuleResult.ContinueRules;
    }

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        string pathExcludingInitialForwardSlash = request.Path.Value.Substring(1);
        string queryStringWithLeadingQuestionCharacter = request.QueryString.Value;
        string original = $"{pathExcludingInitialForwardSlash}{queryStringWithLeadingQuestionCharacter}";
        string replaced = _regex.Replace(original, _replacement);
        if (replaced.StartsWith('/')) { // Replacement pattern may include this character
            replaced = replaced.Substring(1);
        }
        if (original != replaced) { // Case comparison?
            string[] parts = replaced.Split('?');
            request.Path = $"/{parts[0]}";
            request.QueryString = new QueryString(parts.Length == 2 ? $"?{parts[1]}" : "");
            context.Result = _resultIfRewrite;
        }
        else {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
        }
    }
}
```